# SoftLayer API: How to cancel the billing item of Gateway Appliance Cluster

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Our code is to cancel all billing items ordered. But there is an error when cancel the billing item `Gateway Appliance Cluster`, saying "SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): This billing items category cannot be cancelled.".

Can you please advise how to cancel this billing item? Thanks.

Comment: What is the request that you are using to cancel the gateway appliance?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a gateway appliance you can use [SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelItem](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelItem/)

To get all gateways and their billing item ids in you account you can use the following rest api call:

Method: GET

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectMask=mask[id,networkGatewayMemberFlag,billingItem[id]]&objectFilter={"hardware":{"networkGatewayMemberFlag":{"operation":1}}}
```

To cancel the gateway appliance see the following python script example:

```
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Use the hardware gateway id from request above.
hardware_id = 85467

client = SoftLayer.Client()


hardwareResult = client['SoftLayer_Hardware'].getBillingItem(id=hardware_id)
billingItemId = hardwareResult['id']

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Billing_Item'].cancelItem(
        False,
        True,
        "No longer needed",
        "Api test",
        id=billingItemId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp('Unable to get billing item information faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
        % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Reference:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/gateway-appliance?topic=gateway-appliance-cancel-gateway-appliance

Comment: It seems that your script is to cancel hardware(server, bare metal), right? Let me take this order 57056366 as an example. It has three billing items, two are for servers that can be cancelled normally, the other one is Gateway Appliance Cluster (category: gateway_resource_group). If I try to cancel this billing item,  the error "SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): This billing items category cannot be cancelled." will be raised.

Comment: The gateway is a service that will be provisioned in a member, this member  is a Hardware server(the gateway can have more than one member), so to cancel a gateway you have to cancel all gateways members(Hardware Servers), thats why my answer above, use the members(hardware server) billing item id to cancel the gateway members.

Comment: The request above SoftLayer_Account::getHardware that I provided will give you all hardware of your account and the gateway hardware too, but to get through SoftLayer_Network_Gateway::getMembers, use the following rest api call: https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/[gatewayId]/getMembers?objectMask=mask[hardware[billingItem]].

Comment: Thanks so much. All members (associated hardware servers) have been cancelled, but the billing item Gateway Appliance Cluster (category: gateway_resource_group) is still active, and can't be cancelled directly via API. It seems it cancellable via portal, can you please advise why the error "SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): This billing items category cannot be cancelled." is raised? Or how to inquiry? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know when the gateway members are canceled the gateway should be canceled too. Some billing items are canceled in 24, 48 hours or on its anniversary bill date, which could be the next month since the gateway is ordered by month, depending on how the SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelItem, cancelImmediately attribute was setting. To see the gateway state you can open a ticket, they will give you more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will open a ticket.